# ImportError: cannot import name 'DEAProblem' from 'pyDEA'

Tags: python

I'm a beginner level and conducting DEA project with pyDEA but it's not working

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
import pyDEA

df = pd.read_excel('/Users....')

inputs = df[['Counted Rejections', 'Average Cost', 'Items with Complaint']].values
output = df[['Average Gross Profit']]

CCR_problem = pyDEA.DEAProblem(inputs, outputs, kind='CCR')

CCR_results = CCR_problem.solve()
```

it's returning this error:

---

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 14
     11 output = df[['Average Gross Profit']]
     13 # Create a PyDEA problem object for CCR model
---> 14 CCR_problem = pyDEA.DEAProblem(inputs, outputs, kind='CCR')
     16 # Solve the CCR model
     17 CCR_results = CCR_problem.solve()

AttributeError: module 'pyDEA' has no attribute 'DEAProblem'
```

Any help please?

I tried to list the package attributes using
import pyDEA
print(dir(pyDEA))

and this is the result

```
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', 'core']
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems there are two different projects named 'pyDEA'.

[One of them](https://github.com/jzuccollo/pyDEA) appears to have the [`DEAProblem`](https://github.com/jzuccollo/pyDEA/blob/master/pydea/dea.py) class you use, however it seems from the [pyPI pyDEA package page](https://pypi.org/project/pyDEA/) you are in fact using [another project called pyDEA](https://github.com/araith/pyDEA).

Neither project appears to be actively maintained any more. In particular, the latter project has an [open issue](https://github.com/araith/pyDEA/issues/1) in which the maintainer claims the project doesn't work in Python 3.6. I don't know which version of Python you are using, but I would guess that you are using a more recent version that Python 3.6, as Python 3.6 is now end-of-life.

So what should you do? If you are a beginner with Python, as you write, then the sad answer is that you give up on these packages. These are open-source projects maintained by volunteers, and sometimes the maintainers decide to no longer maintain them. Packages sometimes require maintenance to keep them working with newer versions of Python, even if there are no new features to add, and it seems this hasn't happened here. It's possible that there are other  Python packages that can do the same thing as either pyDEA project, I don't know, I haven't looked.

If you are a more experienced Python user and you really want to use one of these packages you *may* be able to fork one of these projects, fix any compatibility issues it has with later versions of Python and get it working again. But there's no way to know how many issues there are or how much work it would be.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, do you know any similar packages to suggest that I can use? thanks again

Comment: @FarahAboucha: sorry, no, I have no experience with DEA at all.